# Unable to get access token from azure media services REST API using PHP

Tags: php, rest, azure, azure-media-services

I have the following code in php:

```
define("TOKEN_URL", "https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13");



 $arrData = array(
                'grant_type=client_credentials',
                'client_id='.CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret='.urlencode(ACCESS_KEY),
                'scope=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices'
            );


            $arrHeader = array(
                'Content-length:'.strlen($this->generateData($arrData))
            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, TOKEN_URL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->generateData($arrData));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrHeader);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $arrToken = json_decode($data);
```

I am unable to get the token code. Please can anyone check what could be wrong?

Comment: What does `generateData()` return? Is it `json` formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few issues:

1. You could simplify a few things and use `http_build_query()`:

   ```
   $data = http_build_query(array(
       'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
       'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
       'client_secret' => ACCESS_KEY,
       'scope' => 'urn:WindowsAzureMediaServices',
   ));
   $ch = curl_init(TOKEN_URL);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   if (($res = curl_exec($ch)) === false) {
       die(curl_error($ch));
   }
   $arrToken = json_decode($res);
   ```
2. If there's an error, the first thing to make sure is whether you have an [updated list of CA certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11997116/1338292).

Comment: private function generateData($arrData){
        return implode('&', $arrData);
    } just returns this. the $data is empty without any error. I am using Windows XP.

Comment: @ShraddhaBandekar I've simplified a few things.

Comment: I tried the above code it gives me this: Get new token from API SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed. I do not understand regarding CA certificates and how to resolve this error.

Comment: @ShraddhaBandekar I've added a link to an older answer that discusses it.

Comment: Thanks could get this fixed. But still there was an authentication failure saying invalid client, code ACS50012. Just to confirm is this the correct client id : tstms.origin.mediaservices.windows.net?

Comment: @ShraddhaBandekar That's a service level error message, so it would be better to check msdn forums or sth.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24817/discussion-between-shraddha-bandekar-and-jack)