# CURLOPT_CAINFO required?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, paypal-ipn

Is the CURLOPT_CAINFO in the curl_setopt_array for PayPal in order for 'live' mode to work?

So basically what im asking is do we have to have SSL in order for PayPal live mode to work, because my script i have made works in sandbox, updates my db how i want it, but only in sandbox, not live. Im not wanting to post my script here I'll open a new thread for that, im just asking a general question so hopefully it will help me, or others in the feature, i searched Google and couldn't get a solid answer.

Have a great day!

Comment: no. ssl will work fine without validating/verifying SSL certs. you just lose some of the security of knowing that the "amazon.com" or "paypal.com" you're connecting to really **ARE** amazon/paypal. But even with "fake" certs, the connection is still encrypted.

Comment: I would be very concerned if any webservice dealing with payments *didn't* require encryption. And beyond that, I would expect said service to verify the peers (meaning you would need a certificate trusted by the CA). Not validating the peer is a very poor security practice that leaves you open to Man in the Middle attacks.

Comment: @rdlowrey, true, and the problem is that the remote server can't technically check that the client is checking its server certificate (unless it also requires client-certificate authentication). An audit could, but I wouldn't be surprised if a few systems out there skipped proper certificate validation for their back-end connections.

Comment: Thanks but thats not what i was asking at all rdlowrey, im fully knowledgeable about the security measurements, what the certificates do, why there usefull and why a user looks for it. Its not the im not going to use them, I surely will use certs, i was just asking for the sake of knowing if its a REQUIREMENT. THanks @MarcB for your answer.

Comment: @AaronRussell I guess what I'm saying is this: it doesn't matter whether or not it's required by paypal. Unless you don't care about the security of your users' payment information, it should be a requirement of *yours* and the question is irrelevant (unless you're looking for holes to exploit for your own nefarious purposes).

Comment: @Bruno Of course you're right. Unfortunately this sort of problem is particularly prevalent in php-land because the default ssl stream wrappers DO NOT enable peer verification by default and users must know enough to manually add the appropriate context options when working directly with socket streams (as opposed to using cURL, for example).

Answer (score 1):

As of using curl to make connection to Paypal, if Paypal does allow plain http connection, sure you don't worry about SSL. In that case, answer to your REQUIRED question is NO. But as you see, it depends on the service you are talking to. Let's say Paypal only allows https for production server, then you have to deal with SSL, either by ignoring it or set correct cert path. Both have to be done in set_opt. And here is another qa for this:
[Source of PEM files for web service access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994658/source-of-pem-files-for-web-service-access)